# Coin flip simulation: Counting heads / tails

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I am trying to simulate a coin flipper using Java and window builder. I have a button called "Flip" when that button is pressed the coin image changes depending on which number the random generator I created generates.

I now am trying to figure out a way to display the number of times the coin lands a heads or a tails in their respective `JTextFields`.  I was thinking of using a counter, but I am struggling with how to update that into the text field, so far it only puts in that I have flipped each coin once.

I am very new to programming so any advice or guidance is much appreciated.

```
// this button flips the coin
btnFlip = new JButton("Flip");
btnFlip.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int headCounter = 0;
        int tails = 0; 
        // this implements the random flip of the coin when the checkbox Run Multiple
        // flips is unchecked
        if (chckbxNewCheckBox.isSelected() == false) {

            Random r = new Random();
            int flipper = r.nextInt(2);
            if (flipper == 1) { 
                lblImages.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FinalPrep.class.getResource("/finalPrep/heads.png")));
                textFieldHeads.setText(String.valueOf(headCounter));

            } else {
                lblImages.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FinalPrep.class.getResource("/finalPrep/tails.png")));
                textFieldTails.setText(String.valueOf(tails));
            }
        }
    }
});
btnFlip.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
panel_1.add(btnFlip);
```

Comment: Please post some of your code.  It is hard to give an answer without it.

Comment: Perhaps something like this: declare two class fields of integer data type, one named **HEADS** and the other named **TAILS**. These would be considered Class Global, initialize both to 0. Random should be either 0 or 1 and is generated upon the button click. If random value = **0** then `TAILS++;`. If random value = **1** then `HEADS++;`. The JTextFields could very well be JLabels since they're only used for display purposes, never the less, at the end but within the button click event: `headsTextField.setText(String.valueOf(HEADS));` and `tailsTextField.setText(String.valueOf(TAILS));`.

Comment: Hmm, @DevilsHnd I had the same thought, maybe I am not writing all the code correctly. I am going to post what I have so far.

Comment: Good idea @AmieJensen. That way we can see where the problem may be lurking.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Ok there is what I thought could potentially work and after I set the textField to the counter I originally had headCounter++; but it only incremented the heads textfield to one and stayed that way even when I pressed flip again and again

Comment: @DevilsHnd goodness! I reread your first comment and I was declaring and initializing with in the button method.  I only needed to do what you said and make the fields that way they are global, now they work :) thank you for your help, much appreciated

Comment: Exactly! :) Glad that worked out for you.

Comment: Well the by far easiest solution would be to simply put the two variables as fields into your anonymous class instead of making them local to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create something like 2 layers. One that contains the window itself along with the title (think of it like a receptor) then you have to create another "layer" that contains the buttons and the textfields. Something like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton button;

    public MyFrame(){

        panel = new JPanel(); //Step 1. Creation of a receptor

        tfCount = new JTextField(10); //Step 2.
        button = new JButton("Press Me"); //Creation of buttons & textfields.

        panel.add(tfCount); //Step 3.
        panel.add(button); //Add those graphics to the receptor  

        this.setContentPane(panel); //Step 4 Adjust the receptor to the object

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setTitle("My 1st GUI!");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

(Sorry for the random example but you did not post any sample of code so I am trying to explain as best as I can)

Then you should put a "flag" depending of the number that was generated for example:

```
    boolean flag = true; //Flag

    int counter = 0; //The counter for the heads

    int x; //The number you received from the generator

    int counter_b; //The counter for the tails

    if(x%2 == 0){ //If the number is even
        flag = false; // You set down the flag
        counter++; //And counter raises its value
    }
    else
        counter_b++;


    tfCount.setEditable(true); //This makes your textfield editable
    tfCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter)); //And this prints the counter's value
```

Keep in mind that the counters for the tails and the heads are just examples for you to understand how to use "flags". I hope that I was able to help you because I am new too!! :)

Comment: awesome than you so much @Stavros

Comment: @amiej33 If this answer solved your problem, consider marking it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of it.